# How to remove key from map in spark data frame scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I am working on data frame spark. There are 60 columns in my data frame and below is the sample map column of data frame. Need to remove 'N/A' key from map. I haven't find any function to do this

```
+----------------------------------+
| userbytestsample                 |
+----------------------------------+
|[TEST  -> 2000050008, N/A ->]     |
+----------------------------------+


schema  
 |-- userbytestsample: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

output

```
 +----------------------------------+
 | userbytestsample                 |
 +----------------------------------+
 |[TEST  -> 2000050008]             |
 +----------------------------------+
```

Comment: what is the datatype? can you show `df.printSchema`

Comment: What version of spark are you using ?

Comment: spark 2.4.0 and update schema in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **Spark 3+** you can use `map_filter` as

```
df.select(map_filter($"userbytestsample", (k, v) => !k.equalTo("N/A")).as("userbytestsample"))
  .show(false)
```

Output:

```
 +----------------------------------+
 | userbytestsample                 |
 +----------------------------------+
 |[TEST  -> 2000050008]             |
 +----------------------------------+
```

For **Spark 2.4+** you might need an `udf`

```
val map_filter_udf = udf{ (xs: Map[String, String]) => xs.filter(!_._1.equalsIgnoreCase(("N/A"))}

df.select(map_filter_udf($"userbytestsample"). as("userbytestsample"))
  .show(false)
```

Output:

```
 +----------------------------------+
 | userbytestsample                 |
 +----------------------------------+
 |[TEST  -> 2000050008]             |
 +----------------------------------+
```

Comment: does it handle the empty map?

Comment: Why not? I haven't tried but should handle, you can try it quickly.

Comment: it is not giving desired output. Instead of N/A, it is removing TEST

Comment: there must ! in filter.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use UDF

Let's suppose i have this dataframe

```
val df = Seq((Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3)), (Map("a" -> 10, "ff" -> 2, "gg" -> 30))).toDF("colmap")

scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- colmap: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: integer (valueContainsNull = false)

df.show(false)
+----------------------------+
|colmap                      |
+----------------------------+
|[a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3]    |
|[a -> 10, ff -> 2, gg -> 30]|
+----------------------------+
```

If i want to remove the key "a"

```
val unwantedKey : String = "a"
```

I create my UDF which will take the column 'colmap', remove the key and return the map without the key

```
def updateMap(unwantedKey : String) = udf((colMapName :Map[String, Int]) => {
  colMapName.-(unwantedKey)
})
```

Finally, to apply this udf you can call it this way

```
val finalDF = df.withColumn("newcol", updateMap(unwantedKey)(col("colmap")))
finalDF.show(false)
+----------------------------+-------------------+
|colmap                      |newcol             |
+----------------------------+-------------------+
|[a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3]    |[b -> 2, c -> 3]   |
|[a -> 10, ff -> 2, gg -> 30]|[ff -> 2, gg -> 30]|
+----------------------------+-------------------+
```